# Python: Split a comma-delimited string directly into a set

Tags: python, string, performance, optimization

I have some code that does something like:

```
if string in comma_delimited_string.split(','):
    return True
```

[This website](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed) says that membership testing with sets and dicts is much faster that with lists or tuples. I know doing `set(comma_delimited_string.split(','))` wouldn't improve speed because a list is still being created before it's converted into a set (or at least, it appeared to slow it down when I timed it).

I was wondering then, (mostly out of curiosity than real benefit to my code), is there a way to achieve the same effect of `comma_delimited_string.split(',')` but directly creating a set, instead of a list, with the intention of speeding up the above operation?

Answer (score 8):

You're ignoring the fact that in order to convert anything to a set, you need to iterate it. And that iteration is exactly the same as you are already doing in order to search the original list. So there cannot be any advantage in doing this, only overhead.

Searching against a set is more efficient if you're doing it multiple times, as that allows you to amortise the cost of the conversion. But the conversion itself is always going to be a linear scan; there's no way of avoiding that.

Comment: Well my line of reasoning was that, for example, for an already created list and set with equal members '1','2','3',... '1000000', checking `'1000000' in my_set` was a good amount faster than `'1000000' in my_list`, at least when I timed it. Given that, if there was a method to directly turn a comma-delimited string into a set that could take the same amount of time as the `.split` method, then the actual membership test might be sped up.

Comment: Thoughts: I guess the only way to make converting the comma delimited string into a set as fast as `.split` might be to somehow write a custom implementation in C, which, as you said, overhead.

Answer (score 3):

No, the `str.split` operation always returns a list and trying to convert that into a `set` will cost time. Also writing your own handmade `split` that produces directly a set will be slower, because `str.split` is implemente in C (the source code should be under [`Objects/stringlib/split.h`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/split.h))

Note however that **if** your `string` does not contain a comma *and* you expect `string` to not be a substring of the elements returned by `split`, then you can just do:

```
if string in comma_delimited_string:
```

If `string` contains a comma, then your test will always fail (because by definition the elements of `text.split(',')` will never contain one.

The case in which the above condition fail is when you have something like:

```
if "a" in "aaa,bb,c".split(',')
```

because in this case `"a" in ["aaa", "bb", "c"]` fails.

Alternatively you could use a regex:

```
import re
if re.search(r'(^{0},)|(,{0},)|(,{0}$)|(^{0}$)'.format(re.escape(string)), comma_delimited_string):
```

However I don't know whether this would be faster, it probably depends on your inputs.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the reply - in my case I'm looking at document numbers which are rather ambiguous (e.g. there can be documents `'10'` and `'103'`) so a pure `string in comma_delimited_string` isn't quite applicable. So I guess you're saying the only way to make a direct conversion from comma delimited string into a set as fast as `.split` would be to write it in C? ....not doing that any time soon.

Comment: @therockmandolinist Yes, that's what I'm saying. You'd have to copy&paste the code for `split` and make use of a set instead of a list. It's quite of an hassle so I'd do that only if it's critical that that check must be as fast as possible...

Answer (score 1):

While a membership test on an existing set may be faster (O(1)) than on a list (O(n)), you'd still need to create the set from the string, which will be O(n). So there's nothing you can do about the time complexity.

You can speed up the test by a constant factor though by just scanning the string instead of constructing intermediate data structures:

```
(',%s,' % string) in (',%s,' % comma_delimited_string)
```

Don't use this unless you have a really good reason to.

Comment: Yeah, I meant turning the string into a set in as much time as the `.split` method turns it into a list which would then speed up the membership test. Interesting reply though, this does act in the same way as checking for membership in a list for any given string. Why do you say it shouldn't be used?

Comment: Nice, on my test data this took only 500ns instead of 2.5µs for `split`. But from a readability perspective, and if speed is not of utmost importance, I think one should go with `split`.

Comment: @tobias_k I understand your point, and that makes a lot of sense for very complex optimizations. I guess it could just be a matter of preference, but I think in general I'd prefer optimizing performance over readability especially if (as in this case) the sacrifice is not too great. I'm only recently _really_ getting into coding though, so perhaps you can convince me otherwise.

Comment: Unless you have profiled your code under real conditions (real input data, hardware, etc) and identified this expression as a bottleneck for acceptable performance it's not worth it to do this type of micro optimization. If performance is important, focus on picking the right algorithms instead. Readable code is easier to debug, extend, and collaborate on.

Comment: @emulbreh Mind if I trouble you for more information? Do you mean it's not worth it especially if you haven't proven that it provides a substantial benefit to the actual code you're using it in? Is an external test showing it's faster not enough? Not challenging you, genuinely wondering.

Comment: The question is not whether it's faster or not, but what you would gain from it being faster and what you would lose if was less readable. Look up "premature optimization" for discussions of this trade-off.